# Denying load of chrome-extension://.../bootstrap.min.css Resources must be listed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension

Denying load of chrome-extension://dlihdalmenebpadfpfmcknhapchalnhp/bootstrap.min.css. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

First off, it is listed. 100%.

My code:

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "RMP",
  "description": "Work in Progress",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.8",
  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js","bootstrap.min.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click me!"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["bootstrap.min.css"]
}
```

background.js

```
// On Extension Icon click, inject script
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"}, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bootstrap.min.js"}, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"});
        });
    });
});
```

content_script.js (not technically a content script bad naming)

/

```
/ Handle page's frame (to allow DOM access)
var page = top.frames["TargetContent"].document;


var style = document.createElement('link');
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
style.type = 'text/css';
style.href = chrome.runtime.getURL('bootstrap.min.css');

top.frames["TargetContent"].document.body.appendChild(style);
```

... more code  etc. it runs fine, just needs the css to get injected so my stuff is styled. (popover)

Have spent a looong time debugging.
[This is the website I'm trying to inject the CSS on so my popover is actually styled](https://mycsuf.fullerton.edu/psp/pfulprd/EMPLOYEE/HFULPRD/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?PORTALPARAM_PTCNAV=FUL_POC_SA_COURSE_CATALOG_SRCH&EOPP.SCNode=EMPL&EOPP.SCPortal=EMPLOYEE&EOPP.SCName=PFUL_COURSE&EOPP.SCLabel=Catalog/Schedule%20of%20Classes&EOPP.SCPTcname=&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.PORTAL_BASE_DATA.CO_NAVIGATION_COLLECTIONS.PFUL_COURSE.PFUL_S200708300709594181035798&IsFolder=falsehttp).

Just pick a major like Astronomy, type 101 and hit enter. There is a frame. Could be?

Comment: Why do you load jQuery and bootstrap in your background page? Doing so should almost never be needed/desirable.

Comment: It's so I can run my extension on Icon click. The extension uses jquery and bootstrap which has to be loaded first in that order.

Comment: But not in the `background` (in your *manifest.json*). Why are you not using [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) to inject the CSS?

Comment: I actually got popover working with css. I used a CDN and appended the link to the head in the content script file. I didn't solve my problem, but it works. Same result I guess.

Comment: When doing that insertCSS, my extension would freeze (not run). Literally added the code above the final insert content script file and it would stick.

Comment: @Makyen You bring up a good point actually. Wow I can't believe I didn't see that. Super appreciate it!!